# Convert log4j.properties to log4j2.properties

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I am migrating from log4j 1.2 to log4j 2.22.0.
The problem is my project contains a log4j.properties file, and I'm having trouble converting it to log4j2.properties. I've gone through a lot of discussion here and it doesn't help anything so far.
Anyone have an idea please? Here is my .properties file. Thanks

```
!log4j.debug=true: Default is false. Outputs verbose info as log4j is configuring itself. 
log4j.debug=${log4j.isdebug}

log4j.rootCategory=${log4j.default.level},${log4j.appender}
log4j.category.fr.bowling=${log4j.mybowl.level}

log4j.category.org.apache.catalina=FATAL

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${log4j.path}/mybowl_main.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d [%t] %X{UserSessionId} %c{1} %30m%n

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

and here is the development.properties for project who contain that part

```
# logger Configuration of file: log4j.properties
log4j.default.level=ERROR
log4j.appender=CONSOLE,R
log4j.isdebug=false
log4j2.mybowl.level=DEBUG
log4j2.path=C:/LOGS/mybowl/
```

no result until now!

Answer (score 0):

To convert from a version 1.x configuration to a version 2.x configuration you can use `org.apache.log4j.config.Log4j1ConfigurationConverter` from [`log4j-1.2-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-1.2-api):

```sh
# Download `log4j-1.2-api` with deps
mvn dependency:copy -DoutputDirectory=log4j -Dartifact=org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:2.22.0
mvn dependency:copy -DoutputDirectory=log4j -Dartifact=org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.22.0
mvn dependency:copy -DoutputDirectory=log4j -Dartifact=org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.22.0
java -cp 'log4j/*' org.apache.log4j.config.Log4j1ConfigurationConverter -i=log4j.properties -o=log4j2.xml
```

You obtain this configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration name="Log4j1">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="R" fileName="/mybowl_main.log" filePattern="/mybowl_main.log.%i">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d [%t] %X{UserSessionId} %c{1} %30m%n"/>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3" fileIndex="min"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %ndc - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="${sys:log4j.default.level}">
      <AppenderRef ref="${sys:log4j.appender}"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="fr.bowling" level="${sys:log4j.mybowl.level}"/>
    <Logger name="org.apache.catalina" level="FATAL"/>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Remark**: You can convert this into a properties configuration if you wish, but I would not recommend it, since it is uselessly complex.